# How to define MetricFilter for AWS Lambda inside Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation

I experiment with AWS::Logs::MetricFilter and encountered a small problem I cannot resolve. In my Cloudformation template I try to configure it like so:

```
  SomeMetricFilter:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::MetricFilter"
    Properties:
      FilterPattern: "*thing just happened*"
      LogGroupName: "/aws/lambda/some-lambda-name-ISW1N3LSLNK0"
      MetricTransformations:
        -
          MetricValue: "1"
          MetricNamespace: "Name/Space"
          MetricName: "VeryVerboseMetricName"
```

LogGroups created for this AWS Lambda has a string of random letters and numbers as a prefix: ISW1N3LSLNK0

Which makes it impossible to configure the Filter at this stage. Maybe someone could help me out and tell me how to work this thing around?

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly one. I just have to define a name for the lambda function like:

```
  FunctionName: !Sub "some-function-name"
```

And then the log group will have the same name.